# Raspberry Pi as VPN Client Access Point

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-stretch, vpn

I installed raspbian 9 (stretch) on my rasberry pi.

I am using shrewsoft ike/iked to connect to a network. (IPSec)

After I connected to the VPN network, as a VPN client, I have access to server names like behind-vpn.company.com which are normally not accessible without VPN.

I have a second development machine, that cant install shrewsoft ike/iked (Android device) and I would like to use the raspberry pi as some sort of tunnel/hub/proxy/accesspoint/gateway to the vpn.

What would in a network sense such a device be called. VPN access client? What type of software would I have to install on the raspberry pi, so that it exposes it's network? I would need http and ssh to the network.

It is similar to this setup:
[RPi as VPN Gateway](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/79740/rpi-as-vpn-gateway)

Answer (score 1):

Doing what you describe is not difficult, but I think the Raspberry Pi is the wrong tool for the job. What you need is a router, configured as a VPN gateway. Find a small router that has OpenWRT installed on it - like the [GL-AR150](https://www.amazon.co.uk/GL-iNet-Pre-installed-Performance-Compatible-Programmable/dp/B01FJ4S9JK/ref=sr_1_1), about £25. It has all sorts of uses, and is a great complement to your RPi hardware.